# arcpy.GetMessages returns empty

Tags: python, python-2.7, arcgis, arcpy

I am trying to access the messages that was logged throughout a script.

```
arcpy.AddMessage("Something...")
message = arcpy.GetMessages()
print message  # always empty
```

The above is always empty.

According to the documentation [[http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/AddMessage/018v00000007000000/]](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/AddMessage/018v00000007000000/)

> Creates a geoprocessing informative message (Severity=0) that can be accessed with any of the GetMessages functions.

Anyone have experience with arcpy know what the deal is?

Comment: I rarely use this function, but i think you have to supply the function with a index of the message. like this `arcpy.GetMessages(0)`

Comment: I'm afraid that is not the problem.

Comment: What does `arcpy.GetMessageCount()` return?

Comment: I'm starting to think this is either a bug or something poorly documented. Either way I've brought it to the attention of ESRI.

Comment: Are you doing anything else in your script beside import arcpy - addmessage - getmessage?

Comment: I am, however I have tested running it with this problem isolated.

Answer (score 1):

`arcpy.GetMessages()` returns the messages from the *last* geoprocessing tool. If you run two tools and then call arcpy.GetMessages(), you will only get the messages from the second tool.

AddMessage is not a *geoprocessing tool*, so it will have no effects on GetMessages.

Basically, if you want to get all the messages from an entire script, you will have to call `arcpy.GetMessages()` after every geoprocessing tool call.